# Ctrl+D shortcut of IntelliJ IDEA in MyEclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea, myeclipse

Do anyone know synonyms of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut of **IntelliJ** IDEA in **MyEclipse**?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut in IntelliJ action is: "Copy selected text or lines and past after current position and don't change in clipboard memory"

Comment: I suspect you'd have more luck if you'd explain what the shortcut *does*. Users of Eclipse may well know how to achieve the same effect, but without knowing the IntelliJ shortcuts...

Comment: Oh,Yes,you are right. `Ctrl+D` shortcut in IntelliJ action is : **"Copy selected text or lines and past after current possition and don't change in clipboard memory"**.

Comment: Does Ctrl+ALT+Down work for you?

Comment: Ctrl+D in IntelliJ "duplicates current line"

Comment: Not only line,selected text in IntelliJ by `Ctrl+D' will duplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a straight one to one mapping. The closest I have come to figure out is to select the text and do a "Ctrl + Alt + Down". That has a similar effect as copy.

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + D in Intellij = Duplicate a line or selection
you cn do the similar thing by Ctrl + Alt + Down or Ctrl + Alt + Up.

Answer (score 0):

If You are use `Mac` the EOF is `CMD + D`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this,

Delete line at caret: Ctrl + Y